# Error al compilar KB Android Genexus 16 U11

Tags: android, genexus

Tengo el siguiente error al compilar en Genexus 16 U11 una KB con Android:

```
2022-06-30 09:14:55,992: INFO  – > Task :WULTUMain:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
2022-06-30 09:14:56,004: ERROR – error: C:\WultuGXServerTPP\Wultu\CSharpModel\mobile\Android\WULTUMain\src\main\java\com\artech\wultugxservertestpreprod\wultumain\MainApplication.java:27: error: integer number too large: 08
2022-06-30 09:14:56,006: ERROR – error:         application.setMinorVersion(08);
2022-06-30 09:14:56,007: ERROR – error:                                     ^
2022-06-30 09:14:56,078: ERROR – error: 1 error
2022-06-30 09:14:56,083: INFO  – > Task :WULTUMain:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
2022-06-30 09:14:56,171: ERROR – error: 
2022-06-30 09:14:56,173: ERROR – error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2022-06-30 09:14:56,173: ERROR – error: 
2022-06-30 09:14:56,174: ERROR – error: * What went wrong:
2022-06-30 09:14:56,175: ERROR – error: Execution failed for task ':WULTUMain:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
2022-06-30 09:14:56,176: ERROR – error: > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
2022-06-30 09:14:56,195: ERROR – error: 
2022-06-30 09:14:56,196: INFO  – Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
2022-06-30 09:14:56,197: ERROR – error: * Try:
2022-06-30 09:14:56,197: INFO  – Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
2022-06-30 09:14:56,198: ERROR – error: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
2022-06-30 09:14:56,199: INFO  – See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
2022-06-30 09:14:56,199: ERROR – error: 
2022-06-30 09:14:56,200: INFO  – 13 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 6 up-to-date
2022-06-30 09:14:56,200: ERROR – error: * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2022-06-30 09:14:56,201: ERROR – error: 
2022-06-30 09:14:56,202: ERROR – error: BUILD FAILED in 19s
2022-06-30 09:14:56,755: INFO  – Failed: Android Compilation
2022-06-30 09:14:56,756: INFO  – Failed: Build All
```

Lo que provoco este error fue que pasamos de la versión 1.08 a la versión 1.09

Comment: En Android toma "1" como "major version" y "08" o "09" como "minor version".
El tema es que en Java si el número empieza con "0" lo toma como octal y 8 no es un número válido como octal.
Ese parece el error concreto.
No me cierra con que pasaste de 1.08 a 1.09 porque está haciendo " application.setMinorVersion(08)" y no con "09" pero bueno, es lo que puedo aportar.
De pronto pasando a otro esquema de nros que no empiecen con 0 (ejemplo: 1.8) podés resolverlo

Comment: Si. Depende cuál sean la versión anteriores , si vas a mantener un schema de 3 números te recomiendo poner 1.10 o 1.80 dependiendo el caso. Eso debería funcionar. Revisamos el caso de 1.08 para que no de ese error

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios y recomendaciones. Cambiamos el minor version a 8 para que quede como "1.8" pero persiste el error. Tuvimos que volver hacer download de la KB (que esta en GxServer) y hacer rebuild all.